# Strings from a machine language perspective

Tags: string, assembly, architecture, compilation

From a low-level assembly and architecture perspective, how are strings handled in instructions differently from numbers? I am trying to understand how compilers work from online courses but ultimately don't quite understand how an architecture that has a word length of, say 64 bit, can understand and relate multiple characters of Unicode that comprise one string but that do not fit in one single instruction. Do strings have completely independent instructions for them based on architecture that seeks a null byte at the end of the string? Understanding this one thing would make compilers much simpler to understand, I believe. Thanks!

Comment: They are just arrays.  Not fundamentally different from an array of numbers.  A Unicode codepoint is just a number.  A programming language makes it look easier, creating the illusion that a string is its own kind of object.

Comment: From the machine language perspective, they are just numbers too.

Comment: "Null byte at the end of the string": is a specific data structure pattern only used by some languages and libraries. I doubt that its use is expanding. Another pattern is counted code units. (All text has an encoding, e.g. [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).) Both patterns have long histories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low-level machine instruction languages have a few string instructions (like, CMPS,MOVS, etc.). These instructions, and the prefixes like REP, REPNZ, etc. are all predicated on the user knowing the length of the string a-priori, so effectively these execute the same instruction on each byte/word/dword/qword repeatedly. These instructions are faster than their manually encoded loops, simply because these instructions also trigger read-ahead of the memory.

These do not assume any NULL termination condition, or some other terminating condition. These also have absolutely no understanding of whether the data that is being treated as a string is a Unicode, or an ASCII, or any such specific format. These are all language specific conventions.

There are many programming techniques that can quickly determine the length of the string as long as it is terminated by a known sentinel (NULL, or a "full-stop") using the same instruction sets.

So, to summarize, the low-level architecture focuses on automating repetitiveness of the sequentially stored data handling process, but does not treat the strings "differently" from a number in any other manner.

Trust this helps.

Comment: Reinforcing that the CPU does not know text, these instructions, despite having "string" in their descriptions, are just comparing or moving contiguous data. They could have been called Move Block, Move Array, ….

Comment: Yup, the x86 "rep string" instructions are mostly useful for explicit-length strings (like `std::string`, which stores a length), not implicit-length (0-terminated) strings.  Without the `rep` prefix, they work fine in a loop over either kind of string.  The x86 string instructions are a distraction from the fact that strings are arrays of `char` with an implicit or explicit length.  No need to discuss them but not other options for asm implementations of `memset` / `memcpy`.

Comment: Also note that `repe cmps` is not the fastest way to write `memcmp` (SSE2 pcmpeqb is faster).  `rep stos` and `rep movs` are fast, but the others aren't that special compared to a hand-written loop.  Especially `repe scasb` (`memchr`) sucks because you can't use a wider element size, and the microcode implementation doesn't accelerate it with 16B loads internally.  See http://agner.org/optimize/ for instruction tables, and the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: Anyway, **x86's string instructions don't have equivalents on other architectures**.  RISC CPUs like ARM have to implement `memcpy` or `memchr` with a normal loop.  Hmm, after reading the question more carefully, I see how this answer makes sense, but since the "string" instructions aren't actually how compilers process strings, I don't think it's the best answer.